# htmlのbody onloadでjavascriptの関数を実行する方法

Tags: javascript, html

以下のようなjavascriptファイルを読み込んで
https://github.com/pekochun/test/blob/master/public/javascripts/bundle.js

その中に書かれているgame_init()関数を以下のhtmlファイルのbody onloadから実行したいです。
https://github.com/pekochun/test/blob/master/test.html

どうすれば実行することが出来ますか？
Webpackを使ってビルドしたため、Javascriptが少し複雑になっています。

Comment: バンドル前のコードでloadイベントにgame_init関数を呼び出すコールバックを登録すればいいと思います。そのコードのあるファイルにgame_initが定義されているファイルをimportする必要があります。またバンドル前のファイルがあると状況がわかりやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: @isirin なるべくコメントで回答することは避け、回答として投稿してくださると嬉しいです。詳しくは[このメタ投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1938)をご覧ください。

Comment: バンドル前のファイルは以下のappの中に入っているentry.jsとentry2.jsとなっています。
https://github.com/pekochun/test

test.htmlというのは実際には使っておらず使用例を示しただけで、実際はviews/index.jade内でonloadを使用しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

game_init自身かそれを呼び出す関数をloadイベントのコールバックとして登録するといいと思います。
当然ファイルが分かれているのでしたらそのgame_initが定義されているファイルをimportする必要があります。

以下に一例を置いておきます。

ファイル

```
tree -L 1
.
├── bundle.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── sub.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

main.js

```
import testFunc from './sub';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', testFunc);
```

sub.js

```
export default function testFunc() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

---

追記

コメントを見ました。
まずbootstrapをjavascriptから読み込まれているようですがhtml内でも読み込んでいます。
カスタムするわけでないのでしたらhtmlのlinkタグで読んだほうが楽ですし、もしかしたらcdnのキャッシュで早くなるかもしれません。
webpackでモジュールにわけられたものを合体ということについてですがモジュールに分けるのは一つはスコープに閉じ込めるという利点があってやります。game_initが定義されていないというようなエラーがでてたかもしれませんがこれはモジュールに閉じ込めているのででます。なのでimportしたところで使う必要があります。

コードはところどころ読みかえてみて下さい。expressを使っていると仮定して書いています。
こちらの環境で試したところ最初の画面にはたどり着けていました。

webpack.config.js
    var webpack = require('webpack');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');

app.use('/assets', express.static('dist'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

app.js

```
document.body.addEventListener('load', game_init);
```

index.jade

```
  body
    script(src="assets/bundle.js")
```

bodyのloadイベントということだったのでaddEventListnerを使うために位置を動かしました。